# Smack API giving error while logging into Tigase Server setup locally

Tags: android, authentication, xmpp, smack

I am currently developing android XMPP client to communicate with the Tigase server setup locally.Before starting development on Android I am writing a simple java code on PC to test connectivity with XMPP server.My XMPP domain is my pc name "mwbn43-1" and administrator username and passwords are admin and tigase respectively.

Following is the snippet of the code I am using

```
class Test {

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{

System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("mwbn43-1", 5222);
config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(config);

// Connect to the server
con.connect();
con.login("admin", "tigase");

Chat chat = con.getChatManager().createChat("aaphadke@mwbn43-1",
    new MessageListener() {       
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
           // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
           System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
       }
   });
        try {
      chat.sendMessage("Hi!");
  }
  catch (XMPPException e) {
      System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
  }


 String host = con.getHost();
 String user = con.getUser();
 String id = con.getConnectionID();
 int port = con.getPort();
 boolean i = false;
 i = con.isConnected();
 if (i)
 System.out.println("Connected to host " + host + " via port " + port + " connection id is " + id);

 System.out.println("User is " + user);
 con.disconnect();
 }
 }
```

When I run this code I get following error

```
 Exception in thread "main" Resource binding not offered by server: 
 at   org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(SASLAuthenticatio     n.java:416) at    org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:331)
 at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:395)
 at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
 at Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

I found this articles on the same problem but no concrete solution 
[here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/SMACK-271)
Could anyone please tell me the solution for this problem.I checked the XMPPConnection.java file in the Smack API and it looks the same as given in the link solution.

Thanks,
Ameya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem as given in [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/thread/35976)

These are the lines I should add before I connect to the server

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("mwbn43-1", 5222);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
```

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a problem with library, a bug. It does not handle protocol correctly. Before the user is authenticated there is no point of sending resource bind, hence it is not advertised by the server. The client should not complain about it.

Comment: What should I do in order to make it work correctly.I tried the same code with Gtalk server and its working fine with it.So I guess problem is with the set up of the server(Some resource problem).Should I do anything on the server side?