# Not able to connect Android client with local XMPP server

Tags: android, client-server, xmpp, smack, tigase

This is with regards to post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977572/smack-api-giving-error-while-logging-into-tigase-server-setup-locally)

I am able to connect my PC to the local tigase server setup locally(I am using Smack API). Now I am facing problems when I want to connect Android Phone to that server over Wi-Fi. I am able to connect to the local server by using client Beem for android.My XMPP Domain name of the server is my PC name "mwbn43-1" and IP address is "192.168.0.221"(I am able to ping this server from Android Terminal Emulator). In Beem Settings there is an Advanced option where I can specify server I want to connect with(which I have given as IP address).If I don't set this option I am not able to conect.Now here is the snippet of the code I have used for my android client.

```
    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("mwbn43-1",5222);

    //ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.221",5222);             
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    config.setCompressionEnabled(false);

    XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);

    try {

            xmpp.connect(); 

            xmpp.login("admin@mwbn43-1", "tigase");
            String host = xmpp.getHost();
            String id = xmpp.getConnectionID();
            int port = xmpp.getPort();
            boolean i = false;
            i = xmpp.isConnected();
            if(i)
            {answer = "Connected to " + host + " via port " + port + " with ID " + id;
            answerfield.setText(answer);}

          }//end try 
    catch (XMPPException e) {  
     answerfield.setText("Failed to connect");
     Log.v(TAG, "Failed to connect to " + xmpp.getHost());
            e.printStackTrace();
```

I am also able to connect to google talk server with help of this code.While making connection with local server I tried giving IP adress as well as Host Name to connect.When I give IP addr(192.168.0.221) I get 'No response from server error' with stream:error(host-unknown) and when I give host name(mwbn43-1) I get 'remote-server-timeout(504)' with host unresolved.

I looked at the code of Beem to see how it connects with server but could not find much.I have also given user permissions for Internet.Can anyone please tell me what lines of code should I add to communicate with the local server.

Comment: It can be a Tigase issue. I can't connect to my Tigase server from Pidgin and Empathy with getting the "host-unknown" error. It used to work from jabberd.

Comment: This solution WORKED FOR ME !! If you are using Android device to connect to XMPP server(ejabberd in my case), you have to use ASmack jar instead of Smack jar. If your XMPP server is installed locally and if you are connecting over WIFI, you need to use 3 argument ConnectionConfiguration constructor. The first argument HOST needs your LOCAL WIFI IP Address(be very careful with that), second argument port will be 5222 and third argument should be the XMPP server name you created while installing it. Then for connection.login("username", "password") you can simple use username like admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['remote-server-timeout' exception as I try to connect to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285323/remote-server-timeout-exception-as-i-try-to-connect-to-the-server)

Answer (score 6):

Try 3 argument ConnectionConfiguration constructor. It let's you state host, port and domain. Host and domain doesn't have to be the same values. In you case, I guess:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = 
  new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.221",5222,"mwbn43-1");
```

Comment: I am facing problem in connecting android virtual device to xmpp server. I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ), can you tell any solution for this?

Comment: No clue. Ask it as another question.

Comment: thanks for looking that, its solved with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981613/3409600) solution

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the host name from the login call.

For example, 
use

```
connection.login("username", "password");
```

instead of

```
connection.login("username@host.com", "password");
```

Comment: @Hitesh Patel  I am facing problem in connecting android virtual device to xmpp server. I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ), can you tell any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the native smack jar it wont work on android try to use asmack or one of its ancestors [android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487854/771300)

Answer (score 0):

Use three argument constructor for **ConnectionConfiguration**. and pass credentials without host name extension.

For example, see below code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("hostname/IP address", 5222, "servicename/domainname");  
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);  
connection.connect();  
connection.login("user1", "password");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have declared the proper permission: 
android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: I am facing problem in connecting android virtual device to xmpp server. I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ), can you tell any solution for this?