# 'remote-server-timeout' exception as I try to connect to the server

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

While trying to connect to *openfire* server through the following code :

```
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("https://192.168.0.101:5222");
connection.connect();
```

I get an exception which says :

```
https://192.168.0.101:5222:5222 Exception: Could not connect 
to https://192.168.0.101:5222:5222.; : remote-server-timeout(504)
```

What could be the reason for this ?

***Note** : I have allowed openfire fire server through the firewall.I also tried putting off the firewall, but the same result.Server is my own machine. The same machine on which I am trying to run the program.*

Comment: is your internet working... have checked it in the code..

Comment: @karan421 123 123..yeah it is working

Comment: ping the ip address and see the response time and also see whats coming using wireshark

Comment: @SuhailGupta you need not enter the port.`new XMPPConnection("192.168.0.101")` is fine

Comment: which os your are using

Comment: @simmant `windows 7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("192.168.0.101");
connection.connect();
```

or if you want to specify the port

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.101", 5222);
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);   
connection.connect();
```

or similar, defaulting to port 5222

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.101");
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("localhost:5222");
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:

```
public XMPPConnection(String serviceName, CallbackHandler callbackHandler) {
    // Create the configuration for this new connection
    super(new ConnectionConfiguration(serviceName));
    config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(DEBUG_ENABLED);
    config.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler);
}
```

or with no callback handler for password prompting of the keystore:

```
public XMPPConnection(String serviceName) {
    // Create the configuration for this new connection
    super(new ConnectionConfiguration(serviceName));
    config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(DEBUG_ENABLED);
}
```

or:

```
public XMPPConnection(ConnectionConfiguration config) {
    super(config);
}
```