# java.net.UnknownHostException while connecting openfire xmpp server

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am a beginner for chat app. I started studing regarding chat app
I am trying to connect android virtual device to openfire xmpp server, but am unable to connect, I am getting java.net.UnknownHostException
can anyone help me in connecting my android device top xmpp server

The code I am using is:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("pc" ,5222);
    /*ConnectionConfiguration config = 
        new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.1",5222,"pc");*/
    /*config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
       config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true); */
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
       XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);   
       Log.i("", "before connecting");
       connection.connect();
       Log.i("", "after connecting");
       //connection.login("test", "test");
    if(connection.isConnected()){
     System.out.println("connection built");
     connection.disconnect();
    }
```

in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and [Logcat](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ) I got is with java.net.UnknownHostException.

Comment: In the arguments of ConnectionConfiguration, you've written "pc" but is your server called like that and have you tried using the local IPv4 of the server instead?

Comment: @kevto i tried with server ip also 127.0.0.1:9090, but still its same, can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) please

Comment: please check your device is connected to internet or not

Comment: yes it is connected to internet, can you come over the link mentioned in above comment

Comment: possible duplicate of ['remote-server-timeout' exception as I try to connect to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285323/remote-server-timeout-exception-as-i-try-to-connect-to-the-server)

Comment: please tell me what you mean by that pc parameter i also want to implemnt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've come across a solution, @devil and I. We simply used IPv4 address of his server.

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = 
new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.2",5222,"pc");
```

Comment: Iam using a local host server ejabber when i give this ipv4 adress it gives XMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
    stream:error (host-unknown) .what should i do pls help?

Comment: I am facing same issue SocketTimeout Exception, please add the answer if you found